# checkbox value always save true even checkbox is not checked in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller

When i add new if checkbox is not checked then save button press value save in database true ,
and when i press edit button if value is checked  then checkbox checked is not show .
so what i want when checkbox checked save true in database , if checkbox is not checked save false .
and when i press edit if checkbox value true then show checkbox value checked , if not true then show unchecked.
 Similarly is problem radio button .

HTML

```
            <div class="modal-content" style="width:140%">
                <!--Header-->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <p class="heading lead">Update Purchase Order</p>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--Body-->
                <form id="NewOrder">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col" id="poidd">
                                <!-- Purchase PO ID -->
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.PO_ID, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "POUID", Required = true })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Purchase PO NO -->
                                <label for="lblPONo" style="font-weight:bold; ">PO No.</label>
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.PONo, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "POUNO", Required = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- PO Date -->
                                <label for="lblPODatepicker" style="font-weight:bold; "> PO Date</label>
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PODate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "POUDate", Required = true, @Readonly=true })
                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Requisition Date -->
                                <label for="lblRequisitionDatepicker" style="font-weight:bold; "> Requisition Date</label>
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequisitionDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RequisitionUDate", Required = true, @Readonly = true })
                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Delivery Date -->
                                <label for="lblDeliveryDatepicker" style="font-weight:bold; "> Delivery Date</label>
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DeliveryDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DeliveryUDate", Required = true, @Readonly = true })
                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- IsCancel-->
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCancelled, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "IsUCancelled" })

                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsUCancelled">Cancel</label>
                                </div>

                                <!-- IsClosed-->
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsClosed, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "IsUClosed" })

                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsUClosed">Closed</label>
                                </div>

                                <!-- IsPending-->
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPending, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "IsUPending" })

                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsUPending">Pending</label>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Party Code -->
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PartyCode, ViewBag.PartyCode as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "chosen-select", id = "PartyUCode", Required = true })
                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.5%;">
                                <!-- SellerQuotRefNo -->
                                <label for="lblSellerQuotRefNo" style="font-weight:bold; ">Seller Quot Ref No.</label>
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SellerQuotRefNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SellerUQuotRefNo", @placeholder = "SellerQuotRefNo", Required = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.5%;">
                                <!--SellerQuotDate -->
                                <label for="lblSellerQuotDateDatepicker" style="font-weight:bold; "> Seller Quot Date</label>
                                <div class="md-form">

                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SellerQuotDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SellerUQuotDate", Required = true, @Readonly = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.8%;">
                                <!-- ComparativeRefNo -->
                                <label for="lblComparativeRefNo" style="font-weight:bold; "> Comparative RefNo</label>
                                <div class="md-form">

                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ComparativeRefNo, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ComparativeURefNo", @placeholder = "ComparativeRefNo", Required = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col">

                                <fieldset>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.WithItemCode, true, new { id = "RUtrue", @checked = true })
                                    @Html.Label("RUtrue", "With Item Code")<br />

                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.WithItemCode, false, new { id = "RUfalse" })
                                    @Html.Label("RUfalse", "With GL Code")
                                </fieldset>

                                <!-- IsPending-->
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ValidateQty, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "ValidateUQty" })

                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="ValidateQty">Validate Qty</label>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">

                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.5%;">
                                <!--TermsOfDelivery -->
                                <label for="lblTermsOfDelivery" style="font-weight:bold; "> Terms Of Delivery</label>
                                <div class="md-form">

                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TermsOfDelivery, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "UTermsOfDelivery", @placeholder = "TermsOfDelivery", Required = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.8%;">
                                <!--TermsOfPayment -->

                                <label for="lblTermsOfPayment" style="font-weight:bold; "> Terms Of Payment</label>
                                <div class="md-form">

                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TermsOfPayment, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "UTermsOfPayment", @placeholder = "TermsOfPayment", Required = true })

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.8%;">
                                <!-- TermsOfConditions -->
                                <label for="lblTermsOfConditions" style="font-weight:bold; ">Terms Of Conditions</label>
                                <div class="md-form">

                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TermsOfConditions, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "UTermsOfConditions", @placeholder = "TermsOfConditions", Required = true })


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button id="UpdatePO" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>



            </div>

            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Json Function

```
#region PO Main Select
        public JsonResult POMain_Select(Int64 PO_ID)
        {
            PurchaseOrder mPO = new PurchaseOrder();
            mPO = mPO_Select(PO_ID);
            return Json(mPO, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        #endregion


        #region Select PO for Edit 
        public PurchaseOrder mPO_Select(Int64 PO_ID)
        {

            try
            {
                PurchaseOrder mPO = new PurchaseOrder();


                con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PO_ID, PONo, PODate, Comp_ID, GL_Year, Party_Code, SellerQuotRefNo, SellerQuotDate, RequisitionDate, DeliveryDate, ComparativeRefNo, TermsOfDelivery, TermsOfPayment, TermsOfConditions, IsPending, IsClosed, IsCancelled, EntryDate, UserName, POAmount, PaidAmount, IsPaid, WithItemCode, ValidateQty from POMain where PO_ID ='"+ PO_ID + "' ", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();

                DataTable mDT = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(mDT);
                mPO.PO_ID = mDT.Rows[0]["PO_ID"].ToString();
                mPO.PONo = mDT.Rows[0]["PONo"].ToString();
                mPO.PODate = DateTime.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["PODate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                mPO.Comp_ID = mDT.Rows[0]["Comp_ID"].ToString();
                mPO.GL_Year = mDT.Rows[0]["GL_Year"].ToString();
                mPO.PartyCode = mDT.Rows[0]["Party_Code"].ToString();
                mPO.SellerQuotRefNo = mDT.Rows[0]["SellerQuotRefNo"].ToString();
                mPO.SellerQuotDate = DateTime.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["SellerQuotDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                mPO.RequisitionDate = DateTime.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["RequisitionDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                mPO.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse(mDT.Rows[0]["DeliveryDate"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                mPO.ComparativeRefNo = mDT.Rows[0]["ComparativeRefNo"].ToString();
                mPO.TermsOfDelivery = mDT.Rows[0]["TermsOfDelivery"].ToString();
                mPO.TermsOfPayment = mDT.Rows[0]["TermsOfPayment"].ToString();
                mPO.TermsOfConditions = mDT.Rows[0]["TermsOfConditions"].ToString();
                mPO.IsClosed = Convert.ToBoolean(mDT.Rows[0]["IsClosed"].ToString());
                mPO.IsCancelled = Convert.ToBoolean(mDT.Rows[0]["IsCancelled"].ToString());
                mPO.UserName = Session["AgentName"].ToString();
                mPO.WithItemCode =Convert.ToBoolean(mDT.Rows[0]["WithItemCode"].ToString());
                mPO.ValidateQty = Convert.ToBoolean(mDT.Rows[0]["ValidateQty"].ToString());

                con.Close();
                return mPO;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            // master grid
            var $grid = $("#jqGrid");
            $grid.jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("POGrid")',
                datatype: "json",
                jsonReader: { id: 'PO_ID' },

                colModel: [
                    { name: 'PO_ID', index: 'PO_ID', label: 'PO ID', hidden: true, editable: true, editable: "disabled", align: "center", width: 12 },
                    { name: 'Comp_ID', index: 'Comp_ID', label: 'Comp ID', hidden: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, align: "left", width: 2 },
                    { name: 'GL_Year', index: 'GL_Year', label: 'GL Year', hidden: true, editable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] }, align: "left",  width: 40 },
                    {
                        name: 'PODate', index: 'PODate', label: 'PO Date', width: 100,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                        editoptions: {
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,

                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'PartyName', index: 'PartyName', label: 'Party', width: 200, editable: true },

                    { name: 'SellerQuotRefNo', index: 'SellerQuotRefNo', label: 'S Q RefNo', width: 100, editable: true },
                    {
                        name: 'SellerQuotDate', index: 'SellerQuotDate', label: 'S Q Date', width: 100,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                        editoptions: {
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,

                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'RequisitionDate', index: 'RequisitionDate', label: 'R Date', width: 100,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                        editoptions: {
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,

                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'DeliveryDate', index: 'DeliveryDate', label: 'D Date', width: 100,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'text',
                        editoptions: {
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,

                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' })
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'ComparativeRefNo', index: 'ComparativeRefNo', label: 'C RefNo', width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'TermsOfConditions', index: 'TermsOfConditions', label: 'Terms Conditions', hidden:true, width: 250, editable: true },
                    { name: 'TermsOfDelivery', index: 'TermsOfDelivery', label: 'Terms Delivery', width: 250, editable: true },
                    { name: 'TermsOfPayment', index: 'TermsOfPayment', label: 'Terms Payment', width: 250, editable: true },
                    {
                        name: 'IsPending', index: 'IsPending', width: 100, label: 'Pending',
                        editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'IsClosed', index: 'IsClosed', label: 'Closed', width: 60,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'WithItemCode', index: 'WithItemCode', width: 100, label: 'With Item Code',
                        editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ValidateQty', index: 'ValidateQty', label: 'Validate Qty', width: 100,
                        editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                        formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'PO_ID', label: '', search: false, width: '40', frozen: true , formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject, rowdata) {
                            var rowID = rowObject['PO_ID'];
                            if (rowID != null) {

                                return '<a href="javascript:POGetby(' + rowID + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id="' + rowID + '" >Edit</a>';
                            }

                        }
                    },


                ],
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,

                navOptions: {
                    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
                },
                rowNum: 20,
                loadonce: true,
                height: '250',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'Purchase Order',
                emptyrecords: 'No Records are Available to Display',
                pager: "#jqGridPager",

                onSelectRow: function (ids) {
                    if (ids != null) {
                        var data = $("#jqGrid").getLocalRow(ids);
                        $("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/Home/PODetailGrid/" + data.PO_ID, datatype: 'json' });
                        $("#jqGridDetails").jqGrid('setCaption', 'Purchase Order Detail For :: <b style="color: Red">' + data.PartyName + '</b>');
                        $("#jqGridDetails").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }
                },

                onSortCol: clearSelection,


            });


        });
```

javascript

```
function POGetby(PO_ID) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/POMain_Select",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: { 'PO_ID': PO_ID },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#POUID').val(result.PO_ID);
                $('#POUNO').val(result.PONo);
                $('#POUDate').val(result.PODate);
                $('#RequisitionUDate').val(result.RequisitionDate);
                $('#DeliveryUDate').val(result.DeliveryDate);
                $('#IsUCancelled').val(result.IsCancelled);
                $('#IsUClosed').val(result.IsClosed);
                $('#IsUPending').val(result.IsPending);
                $('#PartyUCode').val(result.PartyCode);
                $('#SellerUQuotRefNo').val(result.SellerQuotRefNo);
                $('#SellerUQuotDate').val(result.SellerQuotDate);
                $('#ComparativeURefNo').val(result.ComparativeRefNo);
                $('#RUtrue').val(result.WithItemCode);
                $('#RUfalse').val(result.WithItemCode);
                $('#ValidateUQty').val(result.ValidateQty);
                $('#UTermsOfDelivery').val(result.TermsOfDelivery);
                $('#UTermsOfPayment').val(result.TermsOfPayment);
                $('#UTermsOfConditions').val(result.TermsOfConditions);
                $('#UpdateModel').modal('show');
                $('#UpdatePO').show();
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you did not select `IsPending` from your `SqlDataAdapter` to its respective property of `mPO`

Comment: i have add in my own code ispending value is true but checkbox not checked show.

Comment: when `POMain_Select` method will be called?

Comment: when i use break point and check value ispending or other ispending value show true but not show on front -end this is value is true .

Comment: when edit button click then POMain_Select method called.

Comment: could u plz add your `css` classes that u used for checkboxes and divs?. and also add your edit button

Comment: ok i am adding .wait

Comment: css classes and html code already shared .

Comment: and edit button i am using in jqgrid .

Comment: Do not overwrite the Id of the input element generated by MVC, this will confuse the model binder. `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCancelled, new { @class = "custom-control-input", /*--> @id = "IsUCancelled" <-- don't do this!*/ })`. Also, if `mPO_Select` provides correct values, the error might occur in the controller action that maps the DB result to the ViewModel.

Comment: i have share all code kindly you can see this.

Comment: two model pop one is add new and other for update that's i use IsUCancelled is for update model not add new

Comment: when i use IsCancelled id then checkbox lock but not show checked.  @Georg Patscheider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCancelled, new { @id = "IsUCancelled" })` and `Model.IsCancelled` is true, MVC will actually emit two input elements:

```
<input id="IsUCancelled" name="IsCancelled" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsCancelled" type="hidden" value="false">
```

This is done by MVC because a checkbox that is not checked will not be posted back as `false`, but the ModelBinder wants to bind `IsCancelled` to a boolean in any case. So a second hidden input is sent with the same name that is always set to `false`.

As you can see, the ID you have overwritten with `new { @id = "IsUCancelled" }` is only emitted for the checkbox, but not for the hidden input.

So my guess is that your JS code only changes the value of the visible checkbox, but not the value of the hidden input. Because the form data is sent using the `name` attribute, your post data might not contain the values you are expecting.

The bottom line is: do not overwrite the Id or it will get very confusing.

Comment: i have remove id value true but checkbox not checked.

Comment: problem is this : $('#IsCancelled').val()    val cannot get checkbox state    if you write $("#IsCancelled").is(":checked"); then problem resolved.